# Class passing it self

Tags: java, oop, class

I have a class that creates the object of type Smo. The object then calls a static method from another class.  The static method requires that I pass the object to it that is calling it. How do I designate the calling object as the parameter to pass.

For example:

```
class Smo {    
    Smo() {
    }

    void sponge() {
        car.dancing(??????);    //////< ----------- how do I refer to self?
    }

    void dance() {
        //// do a little dance
    }
}

class Car() { 
    Car() {
    }

    dancing(Smo smo) {    
        smo.dance();
    }    
}
```

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Use the [`this`](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html) keyword.

```
car.dancing(this);
```

Comment: Duh. :: Kicks self:: I'll give you your check in 12 minutes. Thank you :)

Answer (score 7):

use the keyword [this](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/tutorial/java/javaOO/thiskey.html)

> Within an instance method or a constructor, this is a reference to the
>   current object — the object whose method or constructor is being
>   called. You can refer to any member of the current object from within
>   an instance method or a constructor by using this.

Answer (score 4):

Use `this` to have an object refer to itself. So,

```
car.dancing(this);
```

Answer (score 2):

yup: car.dancing(this);

Answer (score 2):

been there done (this) :D